# Error: Prevent writing to file that only differs in casing or query string from already written file. reactjs laravel

Tags: reactjs, webpack, laravel-8, webpack-5

I am working on a laravel reactjs project and when I run the command `npm run dev` the compilation stuck at 95%  and give the following error. I checked in the whole project there is no file calling with the case-sensitive names all images are calling with the lower case letters.

```
Error: Prevent writing to file that only differs in casing or query string from already written file.
This will lead to a race-condition and corrupted files on case-insensitive file systems.
/media/public/images/user-4.jpg
/media/public/images/user-4.jpg
```

React: 17.0.1

Webpack: 5.21.2

Node: 14.15.2

Comment: Check this https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/25460#issuecomment-526273944 maybe you have a similar issue

Comment: I did the same but not working for me

Comment: If it is possible please share webpack file with us

Answer (score 3):

I have the same issue used lowercase letters and it resolved

Comment: Can you provide solution example?

Answer (score 1):

I got a similar error. the solution is as follows

```
/media/public/images/user-4.jpg
/media/public/images/user-4.jpg
```

rewrite

`[name]user-4.jpg`

I think your problem is path .

Comment: Please use text formatting options available in StackOverflow editor, it will help to improve the readability of your answer.

Answer (score 0):

In my case I had two entrypoints in my `webpack.config.js` and mistakenly had not modified the second one.

So changing

```
entry: { main: './src/index.tsx', another: './src/index.tsx' }
```

to

```
entry: { main: './src/index.tsx', another: './src/someOtherIndex.tsx' }
```

fixed the error